# Why can OverflowExceptions happen for decimal->byte conversions but not for uint->byte?

Tags: .net, casting, overflowexception

I'm wondering if anyone can explain an OverflowException I am seeing.

Consider the following code:

```
        uint fred = 32768;
        byte wilma = (byte)fred;
        decimal bamBam = fred;
        wilma = (byte)bamBam;
```

I only get an OverflowException on the last line (when casting a `decimal` to a `byte`).  I do not get it when casting the same value in an `uint` to a `byte`.

I can't understand why this is the case.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

The explicit conversion from decimal to byte is [documented to throw this exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5d460t3f.aspx) when the decimal is outside of the range of byte (0 to 255).

> Overflow Exception: value is less than Byte.MinValue or greater than
>   Byte.MaxValue.

And on the second line, you should be noticing that the value silently wraps, `wilma` is 0, so there is data loss in that legal conversion. If you would like to see the same behavior as above exhibited for the uint-to-byte integral conversion, you would run in a checked context.

```
checked
{
    uint fred = 32768;
    byte wilma = (byte)fred;
}
```

In an unchecked context, overflows are ignored for conversions between integral types. Higher order bits are discarded. (See: Section 4.1.5 of the C# language specification.)

> The checked and unchecked operators and statements are used to control
>   overflow checking for integral-type arithmetic operations and
>   conversions (§7.6.12). In a checked context, an overflow produces a
>   compile-time error or causes a System.OverflowException to be thrown.
>   In an unchecked context, overflows are ignored and any high-order bits
>   that do not fit in the destination type are discarded.

As for avoiding these issues, use the types that are appropriate to the data you are storing. If the data exceeds the range of `byte`, *use a larger type*. Conversions between integral types and floating point numbers are particularly problematic, as the ranges of the latter values can far exceed the range of integers, and of course data loss with decimal places is unavoidable.

However, if you continue to operate with decimal-to-byte conversions, you will need to keep in mind (and compare against) the minimum and maximum values of byte.